# R draw diagram with custom coefficients

Tags: r, diagram, sem

I want to draw the following diagram in R:
[image]

I saw that the `lavaan` package has a function to build diagrams, however you need to provide an already fitted model. I just want to build the diagram above with my own coefficients and use it in Rmarkdown. Is there any straightforward way to achieve this? Colors are not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("
digraph {
node [shape=none] IV1; IV2; MED; DV

IV1 -> MED [label=3.2] 
IV1 -> DV [label=0.2] 
IV2 -> DV [label=9.3]
IV2 -> MED [label=0.5]
MED -> DV [label=5.1]
}"
)
```

Giving

[image]

There are vast options for customisation.  See [here](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. And do you know if it would be possible to adjust the shape so that it resembles mine? You don't necessarily have to do it, just would like to know if it is possible before diving into it.

Comment: It should be.  I'm not an expert on the package.  The link I gave you is a starting point.  Beyond that, there's always Google:  a search on "diagrammer position node" gave me `set_node_position()` as the [first hit](https://rdrr.io/cran/DiagrammeR/man/set_node_position.html), for example.

Comment: See also [this](https://observablehq.com/@magjac/placing-graphviz-nodes-in-fixed-positions), which lets you play interactively.

Comment: You're welcome.  There also appears to be syntax for specifying node positions inside the `[]`.   The availability of some options appear to depend on the graph layout (ie dot, neato, twopi, circo, etc).  Some posts suggest the `rank` attribute may helpful - and less fiddly than using absolute position.  Direction `LR` also appears to be an option. :=)

Comment: I will have a look into that, thanks for the extra information!